# UDFs Use Array to Split String in Column

Tags: arrays, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a df that has two columns. One column is a string and the other is an array of integers.

```
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

The dataframe looks like:

```
+--------------------+------------+
|                col1|        col2|
+--------------------+------------+
|Barkley likes peo...|[22, 22, 25]|
+--------------------+------------+
```

The array actually tells me where I need to break apart the sentences in col1.

If the value then in col1 is "Barkley likes people. Barkley likes treats. Barkley likes everything." The array tells me that from 0-22 chars is the first sentence, from 22 to 44 (22+22) is the second sentence and the last sentence then is from 44(22+22) to 69 (44+25).

I need to avoid sending anything to the driver node and maintain parallelism. My question then is how can I create a udf that leverages the integers in my array to split the sentence in col1? The output could leverage withColumn and return three new columns or a map with each sentence. Can I do this without a for loop, list comprehension, collect() or select()?

Comment: what's the spark version?

Comment: spark version is 3.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Spark version >= 2.4, we can utilize higher-order functions to work with arrays, including this problem. Let's say `df` is the dataframe.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
           ("Barkley likes people. Barkley likes treats. Barkley likes everything.",[22, 22, 25]),
           ("A sentence. Another sentence.",[13, 18]),
           ("One sheep. Two sheep. Three sheep. Four sheep.",[11, 12, 13, 12])], 
           "col1:string, col2:array<int>")
df.show()
# +--------------------+----------------+
# |                col1|            col2|
# +--------------------+----------------+
# |Barkley likes peo...|    [22, 22, 25]|
# |A sentence. Anoth...|        [13, 18]|
# |One sheep. Two sh...|[11, 12, 13, 12]|
# +--------------------+----------------+
```

To slice the sentences from `col1`, `substring` function will used and it needs arguments of *start position* and *length*. `col2` is the lengths of every sentences in the string. The start positions of every sentences are the cumulative sum of array `col2` from 0 to n-1, as hinted in the question. To get that, use higher-order functions `transform` and `aggregate`. After that, get every sentences and use `map_from_entries` to create a map for every sentences and their indexes. This is an example to do so.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = (df
      .withColumn("start", F.expr("transform(transform(col2, (v1,i) -> slice(col2, 1, i)), v2 -> aggregate(v2, 0, (a,b) -> a + b))"))
      .withColumn("sentences", F.expr("transform(col2, (v, i) -> struct(i+1 as index, substring(col1, start[i], col2[i]) as sentence))"))
      .selectExpr("col1", "map_from_entries(sentences) as sentences")
      )
df.show(truncate=False)
# +---------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |col1                                                                 |sentences                                                                                 |
# +---------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |Barkley likes people. Barkley likes treats. Barkley likes everything.|[1 -> Barkley likes people. , 2 ->  Barkley likes treats., 3 ->  Barkley likes everything]|
# |A sentence. Another sentence.                                        |[1 -> A sentence. A, 2 -> Another sentence.]                                              |
# |One sheep. Two sheep. Three sheep. Four sheep.                       |[1 -> One sheep. , 2 ->  Two sheep. , 3 -> Three sheep. , 4 -> Four sheep.]               |
# +---------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Will map_from_entries move all data to the machine with the driver? I am dealing with a very large volume of data.

Comment: I believe no, `map_from_entries` as well as array functions and higher-order functions are narrow transformations that do not require data to be moved.